# How to check file type using Mocha/Chai?

Tags: node.js, api, testing, mocha.js, chai

The function should be testing three conditions 1)status is 200  2)response is in HTML form  3)text of the response is equal to index.html.  My Code is as follow

```
const index = fs.readFileSync('../index.html');
describe('GET / path', () => {
    it('it should GET the index.html' ,(done) => {
        chai.request(server)
            .get('/')
            .end((err, res) => { 
                res.should.have.status(200); 
                res.body.should.be.html;
                res.text.should.be.eql(index);
                done();
            });
    });
});
```

But this function is giving an error

```
 1) Going through the routes
   GET / path
     it should GET the index.html:
 Uncaught AssertionError: expected {} to have headers or getHeader method
  at Assertion.<anonymous> (node_modules\chai-http\lib\http.js:224:40)
  at Assertion.propertyGetter (node_modules\chai\lib\chai\utils\addProperty.js:62:29)
  at Object.get (<anonymous>)
  at Object.proxyGetter [as get] (node_modules\chai\lib\chai\utils\proxify.js:98:22)
```

Is there any problem with my third condition??

Answer (score 1):

To get the content type you want, you need something like this (I use expect, not should, but is the same):

```js
expect(res.headers['content-type']).to.have.string('text/html');
```

Header response has an attribute where you can get the response format. It will be HTML if value is `text/html; charset=utf-8` so you can check if the string match or starts with `text/html`.

Note that node object attributes can be accessed as if it were an array, so using the object key `'content-type'` you will get the required value.